# Strange GPG error. apt-get doesn't work anymore

Tags: 12.04, apt, update-manager, gnupg

If I run anything apt-get related, I get this error:

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D6B6DB186A68F637
```

Please how can I fix this?

Comment: @JorgeCastro post edited after applying the suggested answer. Now it's left with the GPG error

Comment: Looks more like this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey

Answer (score 1):

Try re-adding the PPA to your system, and checking for updates: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-4-0 && sudo apt-get update`. This should hopefully cause your system to re-download the pgp key, thus hopefully fixing the issue.

Comment: Question edited pls can you edit your answer accordingly?

Comment: It seems you need to download a pubkey, but I'm not sure which key you might need. Try running `sudo apt-get update`, and post the full output. Perhaps something there will be more detailed errors that might help give us a clue as to what might be going on.